# 'Restore purchase' required for auto renewable App Store subscriptions?

Tags: ios, swift, subscription

Are 'Restore Purchase' required for an app with auto-renewable subscription?

I don't see why, since if user just logs in with their credentials we can verify the subscription. Also if they change their phone. Can someone enlight if and why it's required?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can verify subscription using transaction history receipt. but after reset a receipt is not available. You need to restore Purchase for retrieving transaction which is already completed. So, you have to put Restore Button in UI.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases), you have to show a `restore purchase` button:

> If your app sells non-consumable, **auto-renewable subscription**, or non-renewing subscription products, **you must provide a UI that allows them to be restored**. Your customers expect your content to be available on all their devices and indefinitely